# "not to know A from B" VS "not to know a B from a bull's foot"?

Tags: idioms, comparison

I've been doing some research and I came across the idioms "not to know A from B" and "not to know a B from a bull's foot". As far as I know they seem to have the same meaning "to be ignorant" or "to know nothing". But I believe that somehow the 2nd one is more emphatic than the 1st one, but this is just my personal feeling. I'd like to know what do you think about this. Are they the same?

Comment: There are lots of variations - [he doesn't know his ass from his elbow](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=1400499), for example.

Comment: There is a similar type phrase, "He **can't tell the difference between** apples and oranges". To me it indicates a person with little or no common sense, since the items used for A and B are clearly different.

Comment: Do you have an actual phrase using "a bull's foot? Haven't heard that one before.

Comment: I can't find it anywhere and I've never heard it too.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: They are the same.

"not to know a B from a bull's foot" might be used in some rural places, or some non-USA places, but I've never heard of it.  Other similar phrases (besides the "his ass from his elbow" mentioned above are "he doesn't know his ass from a hole in the ground" and "he doesn't know shit from Shinola".  Shinola is or was a brand of shoe polish.

I don't think there is really any difference in the meaning of these.  It's really a difference in where they can be said.  I suspect that somebody wanted to say "shit from Shinola" in a place where that would be a dirty word, so he changed it to "A from B" to clean it up.  Even if that's not what really happened, I would prefer using these in this order:

- shit from Shinola
- his ass from a hole in the ground
- his ass from his elbow
- A from B

That is, I will use the highest one on the list that is compatible with the place I'm at and people I'm with.  I can't imagine myself using "A from B"--If I were someplace where I couldn't say one of the other ones, I wouldn't say anything like that.  The point of this sort of phrasing is in the humor.  In fact, if there is any difference at all in them, "A from B" might be stronger, because the person saying it is insisting on calling this guy dumb without a bit of humor lightening it up.

Ignore the fact that in real life it is easier to distinguish one's ass from one's elbow than it is to distinguish one's ass from a hole in the ground.  And it's harder than both of those to distinguish shit from Shinola.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree that the two phrases have the same meaning, I'd suggest that they do not exactly mean "to be ignorant" or "to know nothing". In both cases not only is ignorance asserted, but lack of perception or judgement (common sense) as well. As has been pointed out, the items being compared are obviously different, although the "sh** from Shinola" is slightly different, since Shinola was a brown shoe polish, and might be mistaken for the other, except for the smell. It was the alliteration which made the saying popular.

An illustration of this is the use of the construction in specialized fields of knowledge, where ignorance of the difference between two subjects would not be obvious to non-practitioners. For instance http://www.buzzfeed.com/jonstone/david-cameron-doesnt-know-the-difference-between-middlesbrou asserts that "David Cameron Doesn’t Know The Difference Between Middlesbrough And Newcastle". Well, neither do I, frankly, and I doubt anyone will hold it against me, but it matters to British that their Prime Minister doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

My father, Geoff Hyles, used the "B from bull's foot" expression all the time. He was a farmer/grazier in the Queanbeyan/Canberra district. But he used it more as a justification for (typically) the city person's lack of knowledge/empathy/uderstanding than as a criticism of that person. A city person, one who did not understand the ways and life of a country/rural person. "The country folks has pleasures wot the city folks don't knows." Or, "He doesn't know which end the grass goes in."
It's an old expression but probably has more relevance today than ever before. 100 years ago most Australian families had relatives who were farmers - and so they knew a bit about the farm and fdarm life. Today, so many kids think milk grows in the supermarket. It's a tough life in the Oz bush these days and it's becoming ever increasingly divorced from the comforts of the city.